# Passing a JS variable to getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a small website where I want to switch tabs based on the variable passed in the URL. Here's the logic I have currently written.

```
var hash = window.location.href.split("#");
var count = hash.length;
if(count > 0){
    var blockid = hash[1];

    document.getElementById(hash[1]).css("display","block");
    //document.getElementById("showthisdiv").css("display","block"); - this works

    document.getElementById("broken_href").innerHTML = blockid; 
}

    <div class="broken_href"> </div>
```

hash[1] is the name of the div that I want to change the style of. If I change the hash[1] and write the name of the div in the GetElementById it works fine. 
Also just to test i created a dummy div to see what value was being held by the blockid. It is passing the value correctly.

URL for testing would be something like:

```
    http://localhost/test/#showthisdiv
```

What do i need to do to solve this?

Comment: name? Do you mean ID, right?! But here you are trying to use css jquery method on DOM node, not jq object

Comment: @A.Wolff - yup i meant the id. my bad, when i was typing it, got over-excited.

Comment: `document.getElementById()` won't return anything with a `css` method.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - that is why i printed it in a div, so that i could find the result was passing through properly. works fine.

Comment: @Quentin it will return an error i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff — Well, it will throw one, but that contradicts what the OP says "If I change the hash[1] and write the name of the div in the GetElementById it works fine" (which implies that this isn't the problematic code)

Comment: @Quentin you are correct! Doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This row is your problem

```
document.getElementById(hash[1]).css("display","block");
```

This .css method is a jQuery method and is not available in basic Javascript.

You could use:

```
 document.getElementById(hash[1]).style.display = "block";
```

Or include jQuery and use:

```
$("#"+hash[1]).css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use css jquery method on DOM node, not on jq object

Use that instead:

```
$('#'+hash[1]).show();
```

Comment: @Tibos css() jq's method is for jq object, not DOM node

Comment: `.css` is a jQuery function used on jQuery elements. Without jQuery, its : `document.getElementById(hash[1]).style.display = 'block';`

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah, i didn't notice. Still, it would be nice to say in the answer what the problem is, not just the solution.

Comment: @A.Wolff was commenting to the OP ;)

Comment: @Tibos i said it in comment, first one below OP's question but you are right

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

and then

```
document.getElementById(hash.substring(1)).style.display = "block";
```

If you use jQuery you can do this directly:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
...
$(hash).show();
```

`window.location.hash` returns a value like this: `#some-hash`. This is the reason for what you need to use `substring(1)` when calling `getElementById`.

Comment: css is a jquery method

Comment: @A.Wolff Whoups! Thank you. I just copied the code from question.

Comment: Be careful when using `window.location.hash` as not all browsers actually return the `#` as a prefix. In my code I use this: `var hash = '#' + location.hash.replace('#', ''); // some browsers don't give the hash`